# Cypher java date query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm attempting to run a cypher query to return back nodes within a particular date range. When passing in the date object (Java) the query fails to return the correct nodes. I'm currently using the long date value (i.e. getTime()) which works as expected. This is great, but is there a way of just using the actual Date object?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately neo4j has no support for storing actual date objects as properties. So, right now you have to pass in `date.getTime()` as cypher parameters.

We'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

It has been integrated in Neo4j 2.0, see [timestamp](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-timestamp).